# Alternatives to webview?

Tags: android, android-webview, chrome-custom-tabs

I have came across many such post which talks about Crosswalk and Chrome Custom tabs but each of them have problems

**My Requirements:** 
I need to redirect my users to external web applications like flipkart.com, myntra.com etc and monitor the URLs user is visiting

**Problem with webview:**

"Sign in With Google" doesn't work in webview (google prompt for using chrome custom tab) which forces my user to opt for login with other options (not good experience).

Apart from this in some circumstances which happens in adhoc way, some ajax event doesn't invoke which are very critical for my application like "Tracking if user buys something", My affiliates do not receive hit when host website invokes it.

**Problem with chrome custom tab:**

It works great but doesn't provide a way to monitor visited URLs

**Problem with Crosswalk:**

Its awfully heavy and i have read that its not even production ready.

Is there any alternative that works like chrome custom tab but allows url monitoring?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe working with Firebase Real-time database can help. You can create a user for each signed up user and on button click monitor what website did the user visit.

WIM You can add the url the user visited to ur database.

Comment: Doesnt answer my question, firebase database can hold data but i need a browser which lets me monitor visited urls